# Seeding/Creating many-to-many relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I have tow models Winner and Competition, a winner may have won many competitions and a competition may have been won by many winners, this to me is a many-to-many relationship.

Now I created my two migrations and pivot table migration:

```
Schema::create('winners', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('instagram');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('competitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('winner_competition', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('winner_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('competition_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('winner_id')->references('id')->on('winners')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('competition_id')->references('id')->on('competitions')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

Now I want to seed create a few winners but I don't know how I should assign a competition to a winner in seed file and controller method:

```
public function create(Create $request)
    {
        $winner = new Winner();
        $winner->instagram = $request->input('instagram');
        $winner->competition_id = '?';
        $winner->save();

        return response()->json([
            'winner' => $winner
        ]);
    }

DB::table('winners')->insert([
            'instagram' => '@hfgfgdhdd',
            'competition_id' => '?'
        ]);
```

Someone shed some light on me.

Answer (score 0):

So far, as you have many to many relationship:

```php
$winner = new Winner();
$winner->instagram = $request->input('instagram');
$winner->save(); //add record in the DB
$competition = Competition::where(/**/); // <- you have to query certain competition here
$competition->winners()->attach($winner->id); //add record in the pivot table without check if such winner_id-competition_id pair exists
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Your models must have [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) defined:

```php
//Winner model
public function competitions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Competition::class);
    //you can pass table name as 2nd parameter:
    //return $this->belongsToMany(Competition::class, 'winner_competition');
}

//Competition model
public function winners()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Winner::class);
}
```

P. S. You can go even simpler with creating new Winner:

```php
$winner = Winner::create(['instagram' => $request->input('instagram')]);
$competition = Competition::where(/**/);
$competition->winners()->attach($winner->id);
```

Comment: Does it matter if I attach winner to competition instead?

Comment: Competition to winner, you mean? No, it doesn't